# Enabling/Calculating Storage metrics

Tags: 2013, storage, metrics

If I go in the storage metrics of my Sharepoint 2013 the most items has the following:

```
Not available   0,00%   30.12.1899 01:00
```

Is there something to set? 
How do I recalculate it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute this command in PowerShell:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "https://your site"
$site.RecalculateStorageMetrics()
```

Comment: Shouldn't they be recalculated automatically any user input?